# How to force a table into page width?

Tags: tables, margins

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table) [inner sep=0pt] {
\begin{tabular}{ l | l }
  {\bf Symptom} & {\bf Metric} \\
\hline
Class that has many accessor methods and accesses a lot of external data & ATFD is more than a few\\
Class that is large and complex & WMC is high\\
Class that has a lot of methods that only operate on a proper subset of the instance variable set & TCC is low\\
\end{tabular}
};
\draw [rounded corners=.5em] (table.north west) rectangle (table.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{God class symptoms}
\label{tbl:god_class}
\end{table}
```

Now I want to force the width of the table to be the same as the `\textwidth`, either by linewrapping of table text or by scaling. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should not use `{\bf <text>}` but `\textbf{<text>}` or `\bfseries` instead! Same is true for `\it` and `\tt` or how they are called. They are all deprecated. Please see the [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu) document for this and other things.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

You can use the [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package. It allows you to set the width of the table and provides the `X` column type, which fills out the rest of the space. It can be used for several columns, which then share the rest of the width equally.

Example:

```
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
% ....
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|l}
  \textbf{Symptom} & \textbf{Metric} \\
\hline
Class that has many accessor methods and accesses a lot of external data & ATFD is more than a few\\
Class that is large and complex & WMC is high\\
Class that has a lot of methods that only operate on a proper subset of the instance variable set & TCC is low\\
\end{tabularx}
```

In general it is also possible to set the width of a column using `p{<width>}` instead of `l` as column type. Then it will be formatted as a paragraph and can include line breaks. Replace `<width>` with the required width.

Comment: If you're considering `tabularx` you might also consider its less well known (but sometimes better behaved) sibling `tabulary`

Comment: How can we adjust the width of the columns?

Comment: I think this method does work when the table is small and you need to adjust it to fit the text width. However, it does not work when you have a large table that is overflowing the margins and you need it to be compressed.

Comment: This does not work on two columns and exceeds the page. @Martin Scharrer♦

Comment: Use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X` instead of just `X` to center the text in the column.

Comment: I tried `tabulary` after reading @DavidCarlisle's suggestion and I find it works nicely to get `\textwidth`-sized tables (as an alternative to `tabular*`). In my case `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}lL@{}}` works beautifully where my first column is always small (a function name) and the second column large (a, sometimes lengthy, description).

Answer (score 199):

Just to mention an additional method: the `tabular*` environment. Suppose you have a table with 6 center-aligned columns. You can force it to take up the full width of the text block by setting it up as follows:

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccc }
...
\end{tabular*}
```

Unlike the `tabularx` and `tabulary` environments, which work by expanding the width of some or all of the table's columns, the `tabular*` environment works by expanding the *intercolumn whitespace*. Incidentally, when employing `tabular*` environments with the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` expansion device, one should NOT employ vertical rules in the table.

The directive `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` is technically optional. However, it's frequently very useful if the tabular material would exceed `\linewidth` by a bit if the default value of `\tabcolsep` (usually, but not always, 6pt) is employed.

Speaking for myself, I suspect it's the need to remember to insert `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` that has kept the popularity of this approach somewhat subdued...

Comment: This answer is the most elegant one.

Comment: This does not work for left/right alignment for me

Comment: Sorry I did not want to upset you I thought to downvote because it did not behave properly in my case and it was not written in the answer this exception. The alignment I am referring is for instance when I want the text of each cell to be align right or left e.g. llllll or rrrrrr  I would not know how to explain better so I wrote mwe in overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/2294366948nstbmgcjhbrw

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't think that it's a piece of common knowledge"that one should NOT use vertical lines in a tabular* environment when employing the @{\extracolsep{\fill}}"  however sorry for the down vote I did not think it could be taken so personally. I am sorry about that, thank you for the clarification. I'll remove the down vote as you ask.

Comment: +1 for not using other environments.

Comment: I feel that results are same either one use `c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccccc` or `@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccc`. Or is there any difference?

Comment: @amitoz - Unless one sets `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}`, there *is* a rather significant difference. Please compare the outputs of `\noindent \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc} \hline dflas & djsaf & djasf & adfaj \\ \hline \end{tabular*}` and `\noindent \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc} \hline dflas & djsaf & djasf & adfaj \\ \hline \end{tabular*}`. Incidentally, I do recommend setting `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` when working with `tabular*` environments.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a simple way:

```
\newlength\q
\setlength\q{\dimexpr .5\textwidth -2\tabcolsep}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{\q}p{\q}}
alfa & bravo \\
charlie & delta
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: +1 for (a) subtracting `2\tabcolsep` from the column width parameter and (b) not including any vertical rules. :-)

Comment: This solution also allows the full colouring of the row as at the interval specified with \rowcolour and \multicolumn...

Comment: The downside of this is that it only works if alll coumns of the table are paragraphs.

Comment: The comment by @FooBar may have been accurate at the time it was written. However, the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package has been expanded (some time in the past two years, if memory serves me correctly) to provide the `w` column type, which also takes a length as one of its arguments. E.g., one could replace `\begin{tabular}{p{\q}p{\q}}` with `\begin{tabular}{w{l}{\q} w{r} p{\q}}` to get two fixed-width columns with usable width `\q`, the first set to left-align its contents, the second set to right-align its contents.

Comment: This is great. I wanted the left column narrower, so I used: `\newlength\lw \setlength\lw{\dimexpr .4\textwidth -2\tabcolsep} \newlength\rw \setlength\rw{\dimexpr .6\textwidth -2\tabcolsep}`

Answer (score 26):

> Disclaimer: Although `tabu` *might* still work in cases it’s development is kind of stuck and it is better to not use it (for new documents). See also [Is the tabu package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121841/4918)

One can use [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) (e.g). It will set the table to a given width without needing to calc the ration by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {XXXX}
   \toprule
   xx & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

`tabu` comes with the new column type `X` which sets its width automatically. It has an optional argument taking `l`, `r`, `c` to adjust the alignment inside the cell or a numer to set uneven widths of columns. For example two columns, the first on right, the second one left aligned and twice the width of the first one, will be `X[r]X[2]` (`l` and `1` will be set by default). The part between `to` and `{<cols>}` can be any width, and the full part can be omitted to, i.e. `\begin{tabu}{<cols>}`.

`tabu` is compatible with `longtable` with the new environment `{longtabu}`.

---

Adding [`showframe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)and some text ([`lipsum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)) to the above example shows that the table has exactly the width of the text. On may notice that a table without a float environment is set inline and gets indented as every normal text, too. Use `\noindent` to prevent that.

[image: table]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\noindent
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {XXXX}
   \toprule
   xx & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think the table is still somewhat wider than the text width of the page (compared with `\hrulefill`)..

Comment: @HåkonHægland: As you can see in my edit, the table has exactly the same width as the text …

Comment: Indeed but read http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121841/4918 before falling in love to deeply ;-)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: '\hrulefill' doesn't  have text width.

Comment: The tabu package is long unmaintained and it breaks things that other packages depend on. So unless someone takes over maintenance of it, I don't think it is a usable solution.

Comment: @JeffreyGoldberg: Tanks. I added a “disclaimer”.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use the `graphicx` package - I found this solution from the following online Table generator: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/

You just need to add a "resizebox" command that rescales the tabular, see the following:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{table}[htb]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% use resizebox with textwidth
\begin{tabular}{ l | l }
  {\bf Symptom} & {\bf Metric} \\
\hline
Class that has many accessor methods and accesses a lot of external data & ATFD is more than a few\\
Class that is large and complex & WMC is high\\
Class that has a lot of methods that only operate on a proper subset of the instance variable set & TCC is low\\
\end{tabular}% close resizebox
}
\end{table}
```

Note: that this will scale the whole table, including the font.

Comment: use of `resizebox` is not recommended.  using it you will lost control on the font size used in table.

Comment: In the question it was said that scaling was accepted, so I think having a scaled font will be acceptable. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out, I  will add a note to the answer :)

Answer (score 15):

After trying the suggestions made in this stackexchange I found a different and fancy solution (without loading any other packages etc.). The key is define the width of each column.

```
   \begin{table}[ht!]
     \centering
     \caption{Caption text} 
     \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{9cm}|}
        Text column 1 & long long long long long long long text that should break \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: So for the above example you'd need a text block that has width 5cm+9cm+(a bunch of other `tabular` measurements to make sure the table fits exactly)... you don't really specify this latter measurement. There is no real guarantee this will fit within the text block.

Comment: How do you center the text with your solution?

Answer (score 5):

With ConTeXt, from the [reference manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf), section 16.5 TeX-figures (svnversion 329, September 27, 2013) :

```
\startbuffer[table]
\startTABLE
% fill your table here
\stopTABLE
\stopbuffer

\placefigure[none]{}{\externalfigure[table.buffer][width=\textwidth]}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue,

This is how I got to fix it. You can use "m" for the middle, "b" for the bottom and "p" you will need to play a little to get the desired results.

\begin{tabular}***{|p{2cm}| p{3cm} | p{2.5cm} |}***

Comment: what is fixed with your answer? how is selected column widths in your answer related to the text width?

Comment: Unless somehow `\textwidth=7.5cm+6\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth`, this setup will *not* succeed in making the width of the `tabular` environment equat to the width of the text block.

Answer (score 3):

It’s easy peasy to make `\textwidth` tables with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{|X[2,l]|X[3,l]|X[1,r]|X[r]|}
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also set negative coefficients in `X` columns, just as `tabu` package.

Answer (score 2):

As @deps_stats points out, `tabularx` may work when the table size is small and you need to adjust it to fit the text width, but it does NOT work when a large table overflows the margins.

Perhaps a better choice is using `resizebox`.  A sample is shown below.

```
\begin{table}[htb]
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{ l | l }
     ...
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `colspec` function in the `tabularray` package.
Then, use `colspec = {X[1]X[2]}` to specify the ratio of the width of the table.

[image: x]

Alternatively, you could use `Q` column method.

Here's a sample code which incorporate **setting line color, forcing table into page width, and cell alignment**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,lipsum,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Q[1,c,m]Q[5,l,m]},
  hlines = {gray!75!white},
  vlines = {gray!75!white},
}
ABC & \lipsum[1] \\
DEF & \lipsum[2] 
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you have made the table, between  `\begin{table}` add  `\begin{tabular}` enter this:

```
\makebox[size of the table in cm]{put the tabular environment here}
```

This works for me. Please try this.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm.