# latex tabular width the same as the textwidth

Tags: tables, margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force a table into page width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-force-a-table-into-page-width)

I am generating some table as follow:

```
\begin{tabular}[l]{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Input & Output& Action return \\
\hline
\hline
DNF &  simulation & jsp\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
```

How can can I give this table the same width as the text width? For graphic I use

```
[width=\textwidth]
```

But this doesn't work for table.

Comment: you can use `tabularx` or `tabulary`. Please see documentation. `texdoc tabularx` / `texdoc tabulary`. Or check www.texdoc.net

Comment: @HarishKumar or the standard `tabular*` if you want to avoid my packages!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That is also a possibility. And NO WAY! I like your packages and without them my hands are cut off. They are handy and very useful.