# Force Kile to create tables that are inside the page width

Tags: tables, tabularx, kile

I am using the Tabular Wizard on Kile to create a `\tabularx` environment for one of my tables, and I want it to fit inside a page. Currently this is my setup:

```
{%
\newcommand{\mc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[]{l|c|c|c|}\cline{2-4}
%data ....
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
}%
```

However, even with \textwidth parameter my tables are going way of the page's limits.

I tried reading this discussion:
 - [How to force a table into page width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-force-a-table-into-page-width)

But it didn't help, the solution picked does not seem to work.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `tabularx` can adjust the width of the table is to change the width of specific columns. The default column types (`r`, `c`, `l`) are not modified by `tabularx`, so they will not behave any differently. Instead, a new column type `X` is defined, which allows text to break, and has a width that changes depending on the width of the other columns. See the examples in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tabularx).

Hence, when using just `l` and `c` columns, they will be just as wide as their widest content.

If you want the content of an `X` column right aligned, use `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}`, for centering replace `\raggedleft` with `\centering`. The `\arraybackslash` is really only necessary in the last column, but below I added it in all of them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\word{a bunch of text and some more text and yet more text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{8cm}{
   |>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X  
   |>{\centering\arraybackslash}X
   |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
   | X |}
Right & Center & Left & Justified \\ \hline
\word & \word & \word & \word
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So it means I cannot center my text or adjust it to the right? Is there a way for me to do it and still use something like tabularX? This seems like a huge limitation in latex.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Of course you can, just as you can right justify normal text. You just need to add `\raggedleft` or `\centering` in a cell, or in the column specification. I'll add a quick example.

Comment: Ah, I get it, this solved some of my problems thanks ! Now I am creating yet another question about yet another issue :D