# Creating a table fitting one column of a two column style page

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column, ieeetran

I want to create a table, in a two column style page (IEEEtran) but I want the table to fit only one of the columns. The table which I make is exceeding the single column width of the page. Please help. Here is the table

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}
.
.
.
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{hello2 testing}
\label{1234}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    & LfdR        & KLSRf       & MLDFSP       & PNDND       & LDFSSVM     \\
Aa  & 97.8+-2.3 & 97.4+-3.0 & 97.4+-3.0 & 97.0+-3.6 & 99.1+-1.8 \\
Al  & 69.8+-9.5 & 93.6+-3.6 & 86.9+-8.4 & 91.5+-4.5 & 94.9+-5.4 \\
Av  & 97.0+-2.9 & 99.2+-1.8 & 99.6+-1.4 & 98.3+-2.9 & 99.6+-1.4 \\
Aw  & 97.8+-3.1 & 95.3+-3.1 & 96.2+-2.5 & 92.4+-3.3 & 97.5+-3.0 \\
Ay  & 77.5+-7.2 & 90.2+-4.1 & 90.2+-5.7 & 88.1+-4.8 & 91.6+-4.9 \\
avg & 88.0      & 95.1      & 94.1      & 93.5      & 96.5     
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10540/52442) might help you.

Comment: So if the table exceeds the width of a column, you need to adjust the contents. You don't specify *any* limitations/restrictions in terms of the layout or possibilities. What are they?

Comment: @Markus I have already tried those techniques, but the problem with them is that the table size gets reduced but the contents remain the same , that is , contents begin to move out of the shrunken table

Comment: @Markus How do I adjust the size of the contents? The paper has to follow IEEEtran format and I have to adjust this table to fit a single column.

Comment: You need to place it in the starred environment. See the IEEETran manual.

Answer (score 15):

May be this is what you are after:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{hello2 testing}
\label{1234}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{c*{5}{>{$}c<{$}}}
    & \text{LfdR}        & \text{KLSRf}       & \text{MLDFSP}       & \text{PNDND}       & \text{LDFSSVM}     \\
Aa  & 97.8\pm 2.3 & 97.4\pm 3.0 & 97.4\pm 3.0 & 97.0\pm 3.6 & 99.1\pm 1.8 \\
Al  & 69.8\pm 9.5 & 93.6\pm 3.6 & 86.9\pm 8.4 & 91.5\pm 4.5 & 94.9\pm 5.4 \\
Av  & 97.0\pm 2.9 & 99.2\pm 1.8 & 99.6\pm 1.4 & 98.3\pm 2.9 & 99.6\pm 1.4 \\
Aw  & 97.8\pm 3.1 & 95.3\pm 3.1 & 96.2\pm 2.5 & 92.4\pm 3.3 & 97.5\pm 3.0 \\
Ay  & 77.5\pm 7.2 & 90.2\pm 4.1 & 90.2\pm 5.7 & 88.1\pm 4.8 & 91.6\pm 4.9 \\
avg & 88.0      & 95.1      & 94.1      & 93.5      & 96.5
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\kant[3-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have used `\resizebox` from `graphicx` package ti re-size the table to fit inside the column. Also, I have replaced all `+-` in to `\pm`.