# Longtable with threeparttable

Tags: lyx, longtable, threeparttable, threeparttablex

Can anyone help me to figure out why this code does not work in Lyx? Despite using longtable, the table gets truncated at the end of page after overflowing the bottom margin.

```
\begin{threeparttable}  
 \begin{longtable}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{7}{c}}
        \toprule
    Country & N obs  & Total years & No degree & High school & Some college,+ & smth & smth \\
    & & of education & & & & prestige score & income score \\ \hline  \multirow{2}{0mm}{Albania} & \multirow{2}{0mm}{16} & 12.1 & 9 & 31 & 59 & 48.4 & 32.1 \\
    \medskip  &  & (2.8) & (30) & (47) & (50) & (11.9) & (10.1) \\
    \medskip \multirow{2}{0mm}{Norway} & \multirow{2}{0mm}{229} & 12.2 & 8 & 28 & 65 & 47.0 & 31.0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{threeparttable}
```

Comment: Typo, begin and end parts are not spelled correctly. Also you might want threeparttablex for this (which is probably where you got the spelling for the end part)

Comment: Besides: please post full minimal examples, not sniplets

Comment: Yes, please post a full minimal example. If possible, post both the .lyx file (which is just plain text) and the .tex file. For more information see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Why are you using the `threeparttable` code if there are no table notes?

Comment: I'm planning to add them later. started with simple case, and it does not work. Also, i use simple CTRL+L for latex code ,and excluded float table LYX option. still the table gets truncated at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `threeparttable` machinery to begin with when using a `longtable`. Instead, look into using the [threeparttablex](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/threeparttablex.html) machinery.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't be using the `threeparttable` package and its eponymous environment to encase a `longtable` environment. Instead, use the [threeparttablex](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex) package. (Note that its syntax is *not* the same as that of the `threeparttable` package.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a4paper]{geometry} % page parameters
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,threeparttablex}
\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\textwidth}
%% Arrange for "longtable" to take up full width of text block
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{TableNotes}
  \item[a] A note
  \item[b] Another note
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{7}{c} }
\toprule
Country & N obs  & Total years & No degree & High school & Some college,+ & smth\tnote{a} & smth\tnote{b} \\
& & of education & & & & prestige score & income score \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{8}{r}{\textit{continued}}\\
\endfoot  

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\insertTableNotes  % tell LaTeX where to insert the table-related notes
\endlastfoot

Albania & 16 & 12.1 & 9 & 31 & 59 & 48.4 & 32.1 \\
&  & (2.8) & (30) & (47) & (50) & (11.9) & (10.1) \\
\addlinespace
Norway & 229 & 12.2 & 8 & 28 & 65 & 47.0 & 31.0 \\

\end{longtable}   
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, Mico. I'd like to ask if perhaps you know ho to adjust regular table (when using threepartable ) to the textwidth of the text keeping the size of the letters the same ? (i.e increase distance between columns automatically)

Comment: @user90561 - The closest analogue, in the single-page table group, would be a `tabular*` environment: Begin with `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` inside a `table` environment, and then specify `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{7}{c} }` instead of `\begin{longtable}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{7}{c} }`, and (later) `\end{tabular*}` instead of `\end{longtable}`.

Comment: @user90561 - See also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56552/5001) to the question, [How to force a table into page width?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10535/5001)

Comment: but within 'tabular' environment, i'll not be able to write appropriate table notes, i think. or i'm mistaken?

Comment: @user90561 - You need to write `\begin{table}`, `\begin{threeparttable}`, the caption, the `tabular*` environment, the `tablenotes` environment, followed by `\end{threeparttable}` and `\end{table}`.