# How do I left align my captions for tables and figures using the caption package?

Tags: tables, captions, alignment

I have various tables and figures that need to have their captions left-aligned for my thesis. "Titles should be flush with the left side of the table and not extend beyond the width of the table." And the same is said of the figures.

However, I've read through multiple threads and tried various solutions, but everything either breaks or doesn't do what I want.

Most of tables are wide enough that having a title left align to the page margin will not be a problem, but a few (in particular a series of longtables) of them are too narrow and the caption does not left align with the table. Furthermore, I still have the problem of the title "extending beyond the width of the table." As for the figures, I cannot get the figure caption to left align with the figures at all, and have the same problem of the caption extending past the width of the figure.

Here is an example of a table. It isn't the most elegant but it got the job done before the format check.

```
\documentclass{uscthesis}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\begin{longtable}{ccccccccc}
\caption{Predictive Values for (Al$_{x}$Cu$_{y}$Mo$_{1-x-y}$)FeNiTiVZr Phase Stabilization} \label{tab:O_d} \\
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{50 W Data} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{150 W Data} \\
        \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} 
        Sample & x & y & \textbf{$\delta$} & \textbf{$\Omega$} & x & y & \textbf{$\delta$} & \textbf{$\Omega$} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{50 W Data} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{150 W Data} \\
        \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} 
        Sample & x & y & \textbf{$\delta$} & \textbf{$\Omega$} & x & y & \textbf{$\delta$} & \textbf{$\Omega$} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        1     & 0.548 & 0.114 & 9.17  & 1.09  & 0.453 & 0.118 & 9.20  & 1.14 \\
        2     & 0.550 & 0.169 & 9.21  & 1.09  & 0.509 & 0.151 & 9.22  & 1.09 \\
        3     & 0.548 & 0.114 & 9.17  & 1.09  & 0.438 & 0.125 & 9.20  & 1.16 \\
        4     & 0.550 & 0.169 & 9.21  & 1.09  & 0.491 & 0.162 & 9.22  & 1.11 \\
        5     & 0.537 & 0.090 & 9.16  & 1.10  & 0.381 & 0.116 & 9.19  & 1.21 \\
        6     & 0.551 & 0.134 & 9.19  & 1.16  & 0.439 & 0.152 & 9.22  & 1.16 \\
        7     & 0.544 & 0.195 & 9.22  & 1.15  & 0.484 & 0.197 & 9.24  & 1.11 \\
        8     & 0.511 & 0.089 & 9.16  & 1.13  & 0.351 & 0.117 & 9.19  & 1.25 \\
        9     & 0.529 & 0.132 & 9.18  & 1.13  & 0.408 & 0.156 & 9.22  & 1.19 \\
        10    & 0.526 & 0.193 & 9.22  & 1.14  & 0.452 & 0.204 & 9.25  & 1.15 \\
        11    & 0.502 & 0.271 & 9.26  & 1.13  & 0.483 & 0.261 & 9.28  & 1.11 \\
        12    & 0.494 & 0.113 & 9.17  & 1.13  & 0.358 & 0.141 & 9.20  & 1.24 \\
        13    & 0.503 & 0.167 & 9.20  & 1.14  & 0.406 & 0.189 & 9.23  & 1.19 \\
        14    & 0.491 & 0.238 & 9.24  & 1.14  & 0.441 & 0.246 & 9.27  & 1.15 \\
        15    & 0.459 & 0.327 & 9.29  & 1.21  & 0.464 & 0.311 & 9.30  & 1.12 \\
        16    & 0.467 & 0.123 & 9.18  & 1.20  & 0.340 & 0.152 & 9.21  & 1.26 \\
        17    & 0.476 & 0.180 & 9.21  & 1.19  & 0.385 & 0.204 & 9.24  & 1.21 \\
        18    & 0.464 & 0.255 & 9.25  & 1.18  & 0.417 & 0.265 & 9.28  & 1.18 \\
        19    & 0.432 & 0.348 & 9.30  & 1.18  & 0.436 & 0.336 & 9.31  & 1.15 \\
        20    & 0.433 & 0.112 & 9.17  & 1.18  & 0.303 & 0.143 & 9.20  & 1.30 \\
        21    & 0.450 & 0.166 & 9.20  & 1.17  & 0.350 & 0.196 & 9.23  & 1.25 \\
        22    & 0.446 & 0.238 & 9.24  & 1.17  & 0.384 & 0.258 & 9.27  & 1.21 \\
        23    & 0.421 & 0.327 & 9.29  & 1.18  & 0.405 & 0.329 & 9.31  & 1.18 \\
        24    & 0.390 & 0.094 & 9.15  & 1.19  & 0.269 & 0.133 & 9.19  & 1.34 \\
        25    & 0.418 & 0.141 & 9.18  & 1.20  & 0.308 & 0.174 & 9.22  & 1.30 \\
        26    & 0.426 & 0.205 & 9.22  & 1.29  & 0.346 & 0.235 & 9.25  & 1.26 \\
\end{longtable}%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

I've tried using justification=raggedright, but it has the same problem and it introduces a new problem of the right margin of text is no longer being justified, which is also required of my thesis.

I've also tried threeparttable on a non-longtable table to left justify and it broke the entire document because even though I installed the package, environment was not recognized.

I'm at my wits end, because there are a bunch of other ridiculously picky things that they want that I will have to ask in other questions, but for now can anyone advise on this?

Comment: Solution is to use of the `threeparttable`, however as you discover, it doesn't work well with `longtable`. For possible solution of your problem see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278269/longtable-with-threeparttable

Comment: Off-topic: `\textbf{$\delta$}` and `\textbf{$\Omega$}` isn't correct. Instead, load the `bm` ("bold math") package and write `$\bm{\delta}$` and  `$\bm{\Omega}$.

Comment: You write, "I've also tried `threeparttable` on a ... `table` to left justify [the caption] and it broke the entire document". It is *not* the job of the `threeparttable` environment to left-justify the caption material.

Comment: @Mico I figured that wasn't the original intent of ```threeparttable```, but some solutions I was looking at mentioned using the environment for similar problems. However upon further reading I saw it wasn't compatible with ```longtable```. I saw @Zarko 's solution, but I was hoping for something simpler, for something that seems like it would be easy.

Also, thanks for the formatting tips. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need the width of the longtable, which can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-obtain-width-of-longtable).  Then you can set `\LTcapwidth` to the same width as the rest of the longtable.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, threeparttable}

\newlength{\LTwidth}

\makeatletter
\let\LT@makecaption=\caption@makecaption% use caption package formatting

\newcommand{\getLTwidth}[1][\empty]% #1 = longtable index (optional)
{\bgroup% for \count1 and \LT@entry
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \count1=\value{LT@tables}% default
    \advance\count1 by 1
  \else
    \count1=#1\relax
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{LT@\@roman\count1}{\LTwidth=\textwidth}{%
    \LTwidth=0pt%
    \def\LT@entry##1##2{\advance\LTwidth by ##2}%
    \csname LT@\@roman\count1\endcsname
  }%
  \global\LTwidth=\LTwidth
\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\getLTwidth
%\captionsetup{width=\LTwidth}% redundant
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\LTwidth}%
\begin{longtable}{ccccccccc}
\caption{Predictive Values for (Al$_{x}$Cu$_{y}$Mo$_{1-x-y}$)FeNiTiVZr Phase Stabilization} \label{tab:O_d} \\
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{50 W Data} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{150 W Data} \\
        \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} 
        Sample & x & y & \textbf{$\delta$} & \textbf{$\Omega$} & x & y & \textbf{$\delta$} & \textbf{$\Omega$} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{50 W Data} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{150 W Data} \\
        \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} 
        Sample & x & y & \textbf{$\delta$} & \textbf{$\Omega$} & x & y & \textbf{$\delta$} & \textbf{$\Omega$} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        1     & 0.548 & 0.114 & 9.17  & 1.09  & 0.453 & 0.118 & 9.20  & 1.14 \\
        2     & 0.550 & 0.169 & 9.21  & 1.09  & 0.509 & 0.151 & 9.22  & 1.09 \\
        3     & 0.548 & 0.114 & 9.17  & 1.09  & 0.438 & 0.125 & 9.20  & 1.16 \\
        4     & 0.550 & 0.169 & 9.21  & 1.09  & 0.491 & 0.162 & 9.22  & 1.11 \\
        5     & 0.537 & 0.090 & 9.16  & 1.10  & 0.381 & 0.116 & 9.19  & 1.21 \\
        6     & 0.551 & 0.134 & 9.19  & 1.16  & 0.439 & 0.152 & 9.22  & 1.16 \\
        7     & 0.544 & 0.195 & 9.22  & 1.15  & 0.484 & 0.197 & 9.24  & 1.11 \\
        8     & 0.511 & 0.089 & 9.16  & 1.13  & 0.351 & 0.117 & 9.19  & 1.25 \\
        9     & 0.529 & 0.132 & 9.18  & 1.13  & 0.408 & 0.156 & 9.22  & 1.19 \\
        10    & 0.526 & 0.193 & 9.22  & 1.14  & 0.452 & 0.204 & 9.25  & 1.15 \\
        11    & 0.502 & 0.271 & 9.26  & 1.13  & 0.483 & 0.261 & 9.28  & 1.11 \\
        12    & 0.494 & 0.113 & 9.17  & 1.13  & 0.358 & 0.141 & 9.20  & 1.24 \\
        13    & 0.503 & 0.167 & 9.20  & 1.14  & 0.406 & 0.189 & 9.23  & 1.19 \\
        14    & 0.491 & 0.238 & 9.24  & 1.14  & 0.441 & 0.246 & 9.27  & 1.15 \\
        15    & 0.459 & 0.327 & 9.29  & 1.21  & 0.464 & 0.311 & 9.30  & 1.12 \\
        16    & 0.467 & 0.123 & 9.18  & 1.20  & 0.340 & 0.152 & 9.21  & 1.26 \\
        17    & 0.476 & 0.180 & 9.21  & 1.19  & 0.385 & 0.204 & 9.24  & 1.21 \\
        18    & 0.464 & 0.255 & 9.25  & 1.18  & 0.417 & 0.265 & 9.28  & 1.18 \\
        19    & 0.432 & 0.348 & 9.30  & 1.18  & 0.436 & 0.336 & 9.31  & 1.15 \\
        20    & 0.433 & 0.112 & 9.17  & 1.18  & 0.303 & 0.143 & 9.20  & 1.30 \\
        21    & 0.450 & 0.166 & 9.20  & 1.17  & 0.350 & 0.196 & 9.23  & 1.25 \\
        22    & 0.446 & 0.238 & 9.24  & 1.17  & 0.384 & 0.258 & 9.27  & 1.21 \\
        23    & 0.421 & 0.327 & 9.29  & 1.18  & 0.405 & 0.329 & 9.31  & 1.18 \\
        24    & 0.390 & 0.094 & 9.15  & 1.19  & 0.269 & 0.133 & 9.19  & 1.34 \\
        25    & 0.418 & 0.141 & 9.18  & 1.20  & 0.308 & 0.174 & 9.22  & 1.30 \\
        26    & 0.426 & 0.205 & 9.22  & 1.29  & 0.346 & 0.235 & 9.25  & 1.26 \\
\end{longtable}%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: So I tried this solution, and received an error about being unable to use a certain, command with \hrule. I'll try and make some changes and return with a clearer explanation of the problem.

Comment: I don't get any errors or warnings.  You might try updating your packages.