# How to put a horizontal line above the notes using ThreePartTable?

Tags: footnotes, longtable, threeparttable, tnote

Thanks to this post [Longtable with threeparttable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278269/longtable-with-threeparttable) (but the one that I can't comment because I'm really new here) I found that I can use footnotes with longtable, if I use threeparttable package.

However, I'd like to have a line above my notes.
Anyone know how to do it?
(I want something like this)

[image]

Here it's an example of my code. The table 1 (longtable) is the one that have footnotes with ThreePartTable package. It hasn't line above the notes. The table 2 (with minipage environment) has line above the notes. I want a similar line in table 1.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption} 


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\textwidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\begin{TableNotes}
  \item[*] A note adsfasdf
  \item[] Another note asdfasfasd
  
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\caption{\textit{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} & \textbf{Col3\tnote{*}} & \textbf{Col4} & \textbf{Col5} & \textbf{Col6\tnote{}} \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\tablename\ \thetable:
\textit{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}(Cont\ldots)}\\
\hline
\textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} & \textbf{Col3} & \textbf{Col4} & \textbf{Col5} & \textbf{Col6} \\ 
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{6}{l}{}\\
\endfoot
\insertTableNotes  
\endlastfoot
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{23412} & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
                       & AAAA & A & AAAAAAA & AAAAAAA & A \\ 
\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\renewcommand*{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|} 
\hline 
\textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} & \textbf{Col3\footnote[1]{A note adsfasdf}} & \textbf{Col4} & \textbf{Col5} & \textbf{Col6\footnote[0]{Another note asdfasfasd}} \\ 
\hline
AAAAAA & AAAAAA & A & AAAAAA & AAAAAA & A \\
\hline
AAAAAA & AAAAAA & A & AAAAAA & AAAAAA & A  \\
\hline
AAAAAA & AAAAAA & A & AAAAAA & AAAAAA & A  \\
\hline
AAAAAA & AAAAAA & A & AAAAAA & AAAAAA & A \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually, there should be one automatically, if your table notes are inserted after the table (in the `\endlastfoot` section). Unless you want  a second rule, or so I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: If you mean the last line of the table, no. It doesn't appear me one automatically. I inserted the table notes like this: `\endfoot \insertTableNotes \endlastfoot`

Comment: Add `\bottomrule`  before `\insertTableNotes` if you  use `booktabs, or simply `\hline` if you don't ( or any rule  from another package – makecell, boldline,…)

Comment: `\bottomrule` works but, it's too long and too near to the table. Do you know if I can put a line like if I were using minipage environment? Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpYSq.png

Comment: @Eva: Please provide more information about the table, preferrably in the form of a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Depending on the column size, you could probably use `\cmidrule{1-1}` in order to get a narrower horizontal line. What to do depends a lot on the actual table.

Comment: @leandriis Done, I edited the post with an example.

Comment: If you want a larger vertical spacing above the rule, you can use something like `\addlinespace[3ex]` , for instance. If you want a rule at you convenience, you use `\noalign{\rule{somelength}{some height}`. Furthermore, the vertical spacing can be incorporated to the optional argument of \rule (e.g. `\noalign{\rule[-3ex]{4cm}{0.4pt}}`).

Comment: @Bernard It worked with your last solution!  `\noalign {\rule [-1.4ex]{6.7cm}{0.4pt}}` problem solved! Should I write this as an answer of this post? Or do you have to write it? Thanks very much!!!

Comment: You may write it if you want, I don't really have time at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to Bernard!

The way for put a horizontal line above the footnotes using ThreePartTable (and would be similar like minipage environment' footnotes) is:

`\noalign {\rule [-1.4ex]{6.7cm}{0.4pt}}`