# How to force tables to fit across page?

Tags: tables, fullwidth

I have been looking at a few posts... namely [How to force a table into a page width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-force-a-table-into-page-width), but still could not get my table to show up properly across the page width.

Can you help me get my tables on both pages to show up centered across the page although beyond margins?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=30pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating, ltablex, dcolumn, booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\begin{document}

\noindent

\begin{table}[htbt]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\rowcolors{2}{myblueiii}{white}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
\rowcolor{myblueii!50}
\hline
\textbf{Model} & \textbf{NUMUORS} & \textbf{NUMUANDS} & \textbf{TOTOTORS} & \textbf{TOTOPANDS} & \textbf{VG} & \textbf{NLOGIC} & \textbf{LOC} & \textbf{ELOC} & \textbf{} \\ \hline
1 & -0.0516 & 0.0314 & -0.0027 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2119 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.3091 \\
2 & -0.0482 & 0.0336 & -0.0021 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0337 & 0.2088 & 0.0019 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.3255 \\
3 & -0.0517 & 0.0341 & -0.0026 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2118 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.309 \\
4 &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &  &  &  &  &  \\
5 & -0.0516 & 0.0341 & -0.0027 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2119 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.3091 \\
6 & -0.0482 & 0.0336 & -0.0021 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0337 & 0.2088 & 0.0019 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.3255 \\
7 & -0.0517 & 0.0341 & -0.0026 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2118 & 0.0018 & -0.309 & -0.309 \\
8 &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &  &  &  &  &
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage
\begin{table}[htbt]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\rowcolors{2}{myblueiii}{white}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
\rowcolor{myblueii!50}
\hline
\textbf{Model} & \textbf{NUMUORS} & \textbf{NUMUANDS} & \textbf{TOTOTORS} & \textbf{TOTOPANDS} & \textbf{VG} & \textbf{NLOGIC} & \textbf{LOC} & \textbf{ELOC} & \textbf{} \\ \hline
1 & -0.0516 & 0.0314 & -0.0027 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2119 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.3091 \\
2 & -0.0482 & 0.0336 & -0.0021 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0337 & 0.2088 & 0.0019 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.3255 \\
3 & -0.0517 & 0.0341 & -0.0026 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2118 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.309 \\
4 &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &  &  &  &  &  \\
5 & -0.0516 & 0.0341 & -0.0027 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2119 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.3091 \\
6 & -0.0482 & 0.0336 & -0.0021 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0337 & 0.2088 & 0.0019 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.3255 \\
7 & -0.0517 & 0.0341 & -0.0026 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2118 & 0.0018 & -0.309 & -0.309 \\
8 &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &  &  &  &  &
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

First table:

[image]

Second table:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best option is to display the table in landscape format. Since you're already loading the `rotating` package, you could make use of the `sidewaystable` environment.

I would also like to suggest that you align the numbers in columns 2 thru 10 on their decimal markers. That'll make the table much more readable.

Since you're using alternating row colors, there's no point in using `\hline` as well to set off row boundaries, is there?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, 
            headheight=30pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating,array,siunitx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}      % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt} % give the table a more open look
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\rowcolors{2}{myblueiii}{white}
\begin{tabular}{c *{5}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
                  *{2}{S[table-format= 1.4]}
                       S[table-format=-1.3]
                       S[table-format=-1.4]}
\rowcolor{myblueii!50}
\textbf{Model} & {\textbf{NUMUORS}} & {\textbf{NUMUANDS}} & {\textbf{TOTOTORS}} &
{\textbf{TOTOPANDS}} & {\textbf{VG}} & {\textbf{NLOGIC}} & {\textbf{LOC}} &
{\textbf{ELOC}} & {\textbf{}} \\
1 & -0.0516 & 0.0314 & -0.0027 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2119 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.3091 \\
2 & -0.0482 & 0.0336 & -0.0021 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0337 & 0.2088 & 0.0019 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.3255 \\
3 & -0.0517 & 0.0341 & -0.0026 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2118 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.309 \\
4 &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & & & & & \\
5 & -0.0516 & 0.0341 & -0.0027 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2119 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.3091 \\
6 & -0.0482 & 0.0336 & -0.0021 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0337 & 0.2088 & 0.0019 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.3255 \\
7 & -0.0517 & 0.0341 & -0.0026 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2118 & 0.0018 & -0.309 & -0.309 \\
8 &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & & & & & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Micro, thanks for your solution!  For the second table that will appear on the next page, how can you rotate the table 180 degrees?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe - For the second `tabular` environment to show up in landscape mode on a separate page, just encase it in a `sidewaystable` environment of its own. (I didn't do this in my answer as the contents of the two `tabular` environments you posted (though not their screenshots) appeared to be identical.)

Answer (score 2):

By reducing font size in column headers to `\footnotesize` and `tabcolsep` (spaces between columns) to `3pt`, it is possible to fit table into text width:

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[showframe,
            left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, 
            bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=30pt, 
            top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating, ltablex, dcolumn, booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\usepackage{siunitx}                            % <-- added
\newcommand\mch[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize\textbf{#1}}} % <-- added

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbt]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\rowcolors{2}{myblueiii}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{c *{5}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
                      *{2}{S[table-format= 1.4]}
                           S[table-format=-1.3]
                           S[table-format=-1.4]}
\rowcolor{myblueii!50}
    \hline
\mch{Model} & \mch{NUMUORS} & \mch{NUMUANDS} & \mch{TOTOTORS} & \mch{TOTOPANDS} 
    & \mch{VG} & \mch{NLOGIC} & \mch{LOC} & \mch{ELOC} & \\ 
    \hline
1 & -0.0516 & 0.0314 & -0.0027 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2119 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.3091 \\
2 & -0.0482 & 0.0336 & -0.0021 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0337 & 0.2088 & 0.0019 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.3255 \\
3 & -0.0517 & 0.0341 & -0.0026 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2118 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.309 \\
4 &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &  &  &  &  &  \\
5 & -0.0516 & 0.0341 & -0.0027 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2119 & 0.0018 & 0.005 & -0.3091 \\
6 & -0.0482 & 0.0336 & -0.0021 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0337 & 0.2088 & 0.0019 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.3255 \\
7 & -0.0517 & 0.0341 & -0.0026 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & -0.0372 & 0.2118 & 0.0018 & -0.309 & -0.309 \\
8 &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &  &  &  &  &  
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico, of course. I overlooked this option in OP preamble. Corrected in my answer.