# Tabular* \extracolsep is ignored, table borders do not meet nicely

Tags: tables

I'm trying to use a `tabular*` environment to create a simple table with two centered columns that are spaced apart so that the table fills the entire page.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  \fbox{

    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill} } | c | c | }
    \hline
    \Large{Supervisor} & \Large{Student} \\
    \hline
    \Large{prof. X Y Z} & \Large{A B C} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}

  }

\end{document}
```

It ends up looking like this:

[image]

Note that not only does the table not space the cells apart properly, the top and left lines of the table do not come to a nice corner.

(I don't strongly care about borders not meeting since this table will ultimately not show them, but I drew them here to help debug.)

A similar table on another person's machine looks ok, so maybe there is something I'm missing on my system?

Comment: note size commands do not take an argumnet, `\Large{Supervisor}` should be `\Large Supervisor` (although that does not change the output here)

Comment: \estracolsep does not affect the gap to the left of the first column, nor the gap to the right of the last column.  You will need to compute the width instead.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I've also tried `{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c}` exactly as recommended here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56552/145783 with approximately the same result. `\hfill` didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding a lot of extra space

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}

\noindent
\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%SPACE
  \fbox{%SPACE
%SPACE
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}%SPACE
} | c | c | }
    \hline
    \Large Supervisor & \Large Student  \\
    \hline
    \Large prof. X Y Z & \Large A B C \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}%SPACE
%SPACE
  }%SPACE
\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%SPACE

\end{document}
```

Comment: The whitespace around the table is expected by the university that issued the template. For your code I still get https://imgur.com/oWyH30Y — better corners, but the cells aren't spaced quite right.

Comment: @rgov from the exact code I post above? that looks very wrong, can you add the full log that you get from this file (add it to my answer as a code block) or to your question

Comment: @rgov no the whitespace was wrong. you had a paragraph indent, two `\fboxrule`  rules from the `\fbox`  two `\fboxsep` spaces form the `\fbox` but you forced the inner tabular to be `\textwidth` wide so the entire construct is overfull by \parindent+2\fboxrule+2\fboxsep  so you need to set those spaces to 0 or use a value less than `\textwidth` in the `tabular*`  but the other space tokens that I highlight are causing your rules not to line up at the corners.

Comment: I added it, @David-carlisle.

Comment: @rgov thanks (it got rejected by the automatic site checker for some reason but I see it in the history)

Comment: @rgov you have `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 19--19` which suggests that you don't have `\extracolsep`  also (but unlikely to be the cause) your latex format isn't updated you could use `tlmgr update --all` to update your texlive

Comment: Yes, that's right! I uninstalled TeX Live 2017 today and installed 2019, and updated tlmgr, but somehow the packages never got updated. After running that command, it works.

Comment: @rgov ah sorry you were using a format that only lasted a few days, this change might be of interest.... `% \begin{macro}{\extracolsep} .. % \changes{v1.1q}{2019/10/07}{This needs to expand}`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\bgroup
\Large 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}% measure width
Supervisor & Student \\
prof. X Y Z & A B C \\
\end{tabular}}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0}%
\divide\tabcolsep by 4
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Supervisor & Student \\
    \hline
    prof. X Y Z & A B C \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This is a somewhat simpler approach which divides the tabular into two equal columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\tempdima}
\begin{document}

\bgroup
\Large 
\setlength{\tempdima}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}%
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \makebox[\tempdima][c]{Supervisor} & \makebox[\tempdima][c]{Student} \\
    \hline
    prof. X Y Z & A B C \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP was using a broken format `# 2019-10-01 Release` which was replaced by `# 2019-10-01 Patch level 1` a few days later....

Comment: but +1 this is what the OP should do, I concentrated on what was technically wrong in the OPs code in my answer rather than give a better approach:-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you obviously don't want the rules at the end, I make three proposals. Using a macro is a good way to postpone the decision at the end without changing the document proper.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % in order to see the page margins

\newcommand{\supervisorstudentA}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Supervisor \\ prof.\ #1 \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Student \\ #2 \end{tabular}\par
}
\newcommand{\supervisorstudentB}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \hspace*{4em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Supervisor \\ prof.\ X Y Z \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Student \\ A B C \end{tabular}%
  \hspace*{4em}\par
}
\newcommand{\supervisorstudentC}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \hspace*{\stretch{0.25}}%
  \makebox[0pt]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Supervisor \\ prof.\ X Y Z \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace*{\stretch{0.5}}%
  \makebox[0pt]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Student \\ A B C \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace*{\stretch{0.25}}\par
}

\begin{document}

\supervisorstudentA{X Y Z}{A B C}

\bigskip

\supervisorstudentB{X Y Z}{A B C}

\bigskip

\supervisorstudentC{X Y Z}{A B C}

\end{document}
```

In the third one the two parts are exactly midway in either half of the text width.

[image]