# The size and the font of my table change in two columns paper format

Tags: tables, fonts, size

I have issues with the looking of my tables in two columns paper format. 
I would like to place my three tables in the same column using all the width of my column. however, the size and the font change. I tried to adjust the font but it does not look great in the paper. 
I would like to have something resembling the tables drawn in the attached figure that I obtained by word software.
   [image]
Thank you at advance for your help

Comment: you have shown no code so it is very hard to help you or tell you waht to change. placing a table in a column should never change its font, so if that is happening I can only guess you have something like `\resizebox{\linewidth}` around the table, in which case the standard advice applies: never apply scaling to tables.

Comment: thank you for your response. here my code for the first table:

Comment: \begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{TABLE I.  POWER PEAKS WITH GMPP POSSIBLE LOCATION  FOR A 3-BPD SYSTEM}
\label{dataset}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}

\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{GMPP position} &\multirow{1}{*} PL & \multirow{1}{*} PR & \multirow{1}{*} PM
\\ \hline 
Mode 1 &  & & \textbullet \\ \hline
Mode 2 &  & & \textbullet \\ \hline
Mode 3 &  &\textbullet & \textbullet \\ \hline
Mode 4 & \textbullet &\textbullet & \textbullet\\ \bottomrule

\end{tabular}}}
\end{table}

Comment: as I guessed!!  never use `\resizebox`  around tables, it just distorts things as you describe, but also don't post code to comments, edit your question to have a complete small document that shows the problem, in a code block (`{}` button in the editor)

Comment: Thank you for you response and help. 
When I remove this command (\resizebox) I create tables which do not have the same width and this is not beautiful. I would like to put the three, one below the other in the same column.

Comment: you could use `tabular*` or `tabularx`  to set the width without distorting the font.  (There are hundreds of existing answers on site see for example this answer to a duplicate question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10540/1090

Comment: note that answer used \textwidth but you would want \columnwidth