# illegal character in array

Tags: tables, luatex, xtable

have a table like below with a custom width, but i can not run it, any ideas? many thanks in advance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.015\textwidth}|R{0.37\textwidth}|R{0.12\textwidth}|R{0.08\textwidth}|R{0.02\textwidth}|p{0.35\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
        \hline
        1 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        2 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        3 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        5 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        6 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `R` and `C` are not standard column types.

Comment: how can i set the width of the table, properly ?

Comment: @SeymaKalay - For suggestions on how to set the width of a tabular-like environment to a specific value (say, `1\textwidth`), please see the posting [How to force a table into page width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10535/5001) The two leading candidates are the `tabularx` and `tabular*` environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the column widths. Also, you can avoid spreading too much the table by grouping the columns.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  r  % number
  ccccc
  @{}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sepal} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Petal} & Species \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& Length & Width & Length & Width & \\ 
\midrule
1 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
2 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
3 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
5 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
6 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `R` column type. If you want it to do want I guess you mean then you can use `wr` (with a relatively recent version of the `array` package) But this is forcing the column widths to values that are inappropriate for the column contents, and forcing the total table width to not fit the page. Just using a natural widths makes the table easier to read, or better remove the vertical lines and use booktabs package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{wl{0.015\textwidth}|wr{0.37\textwidth}|wr{0.12\textwidth}|wr{0.08\textwidth}|wr{0.02\textwidth}|wr{0.35\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
        \hline
        1 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        2 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        3 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        5 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        6 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r|r|l|}
        \hline
        & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
        \hline
        1 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        2 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        3 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        5 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        6 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccl}
        \toprule
        & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
        \midrule
        1 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        2 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        3 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        5 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        6 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 0 & setosa \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```