# Adjust table column widths to table width

Tags: tables, tabularx, textwidth

I am using tabularx to fit the table to textwidth

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Nice Title}
\scriptsize
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l cccc  cccc@{}}
\hline\hline
\addlinespace[2ex]
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A: }} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel B: }}  \\ 
\addlinespace[1ex]

\cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
\addlinespace[1ex]
 & Linear & KNN  & G-Boost & MLP  
& Linear & KNN  & G-Boost & MLP  \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\hline

\addlinespace[1ex]
avg MAE & 0.201  & 0.019 & 0.042 & 0.057 & 0.179 & 0.181 & 0.056 & 0.059           \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
std MAE & (0.005)  & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.003) & (0.004) & (0.005) & (0.001)  & (0.003)                \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
avg MSE & 0.287  & 0.043 & 0.064 & 0.089 & 0.259 & 0.269 & 0.084 & 0.090                \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
std MSE & (0.009) & (0.005) & (0.002) & (0.008) & (0.008) & (0.008) & (0.002) & (0.004)                \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    \linespread{1}\scriptsize 
    \item\hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font}Notes: Some Footnote here
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Which gives me

[image]

Maybe what I am doing is not right, and I should just replace  `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` with  `\begin{tabular}` which works fine, but somehow I was hoping to find a solution where Latex would just adjust the width of the columns to match textwidth.

Hope it is clear, and of course other feedback on bad code is welcome as well.

**Update:**
If I use the X column type from tabular x it solves the problem of fitting the table to width, however the way it does not look nice.

[image]

Nor does it if I only stretch the first column. How to get this to look good?

[image]

Comment: tabularx has to have at least one X column to stretch, but making the columns further apart just makes it harder for readers to read the table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, indeed, I was just editing my question to include this.

Comment: If you only use X for the first column, only that column stretches.

Comment: Yes, so it seems this auto-fitting with tabularx does not help?

Comment: well you could use X for all the columns (or all the columns except the first)  or you could use tabular* rather than tabularx (that would be better) but I would not stretch at all here.

Comment: For a better looking table, I suggest using the `S` column type from `siunitx` for all columns with numbers, in order to have an alignment on the decimal dot.

Comment: @Bernard Does this work multicolumns inserted? It completely broke down my formatting when I tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=1.3, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1cm, input-symbols=()}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\caption{Nice Title}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X SSSS!{\qquad}SSSS@{}}
\hline\hline
\addlinespace[2ex]
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A: }} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel B: }} \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\cmidrule(l{0.5em}r{2.5em}){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
\addlinespace[1ex]
 & {Linear} & {KNN} & {G-Boost} & {MLP}
& {Linear} & {KNN} & {G-Boost} & {MLP} \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\hline
\addlinespace[1ex]
avg MAE & 0.201 & 0.019 & 0.042 & 0.057 & 0.179 & 0.181 & 0.056 & 0.059 \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
std MAE & (0.005) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.003) & (0.004) & (0.005) & (0.001) & (0.003) \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
avg MSE & 0.287 & 0.043 & 0.064 & 0.089 & 0.259 & 0.269 & 0.084 & 0.090 \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
std MSE & (0.009) & (0.005) & (0.002) & (0.008) & (0.008) & (0.008) & (0.002) & (0.004) \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    \linespread{1}\scriptsize
    \item\hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font}Notes: Some Footnote here
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since no linebreaks are needed or even desirable in any of the nine columns, I'd like to suggest that you employ a `tabular*` environment rather than a `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]

\caption{Nice Title\strut}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{0.25ex}
\begin{threeparttable}%[b] % b??
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A}} 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel B}}  \\

\cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9}

& Linear & KNN  & G-Boost & MLP & Linear & KNN  & G-Boost & MLP  \\

\midrule

avg MAE & 0.201  & 0.019 & 0.042 & 0.057 & 0.179 & 0.181 & 0.056 & 0.059 \\

std MAE & (0.005)  & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.003) & (0.004) & (0.005) & (0.001)  & (0.003) \\

\addlinespace

avg MSE & 0.287  & 0.043 & 0.064 & 0.089 & 0.259 & 0.269 & 0.084 & 0.090 \\

std MSE & (0.009) & (0.005) & (0.002) & (0.008) & (0.008) & (0.008) & (0.002) & (0.004) \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular*}

\smallskip\scriptsize
\begin{tablenotes}
  \linespread{1}
  \item\hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font}Notes: Some Footnote here
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wish I could accept both answers, they both solve the problem and give me an indistinguishable output.

Comment: May I ask what the "\extracolsep{\fill}}" after opening the tabular is doing in the code?

Comment: @Papayapap - The directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` tells LaTeX to insert something called `\fill` between the columns. In TeX and LaTeX, `\fill` generates freely stretchable whitespace. The overall effect is that the amount of whitespace in the 8 intercolumn areas will be the same -- and just enough to guarantee that the overall width of the `tabular*` environment will be `\textwidth`, i.e., the width of the text block. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56552/5001) -- shameless self-citation alert -- for more information on this topic.

Comment: Great to know. Last question I promise: with this approach, it seems `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` will fill equal space between columns and `tabular*` will adjust column size according to the size of contents, so not leading to equal column widths in cases when horizontal space becomes spare, no?

Comment: @Papayapap - Indeed, the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` approach serves to equalize the amounts of intercolumn whitespace; it does not affect the column widths. Now, whether or not the columns *should* have equal widths is an entirely separate question. Importantly, this question cannot be answered using abstract criteria alone. It matters what's in the table. In the specific case of your table, the column widths are quite similar; IMNSHO little to nothing would be gained from forcing the columns widths to be the same (and hence forcing the amounts of intercolumn whitespace to be non-constant).