# tabularray: making a table with variable column separation to span the whole table width

Tags: tables, siunitx, tabularray

I need to make the following code work so that I can get a table with an automatic calculation of column separation based on the number of columns to make it fit the whole `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools,siunitx}


\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{
    table-format = 2.2,
    round-precision = 2,
    round-mode = places,
    round-integer-to-decimal = true
}

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{tblr}{
            colsep = 0 mm,
            colspec = {@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{2}{>{$\relax}X<{$}} *{4}{S}},
            row{1} = {font=\boldmath\bfseries},
        }
        \toprule
        & \delta [deg] & {{{5}}} & {{{10}}} & {{{15}}} & {{{20}}} \\
        \midrule
        \Gamma = x^2 & \beta [deg] & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-force-a-table-into-page-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you want is a both `X` and `S` column? Just write `X[si]` in `tabularray`.

PS: `tabularray` package doesn't support the usage of `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`, and normally you don't need it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools,siunitx}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{
    table-format = 2.2,
    round-precision = 2,
    round-mode = places,
    round-integer-to-decimal = true
}

\begin{document}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {*{2}{>{$\relax}X<{$}}*{4}{X[si]}},
  row{1} = {font=\boldmath\bfseries},
  vlines,
}
  \toprule
                 & \delta [deg] & {{{5}}} & {{{10}}} & {{{15}}} & {{{20}}} \\
  \midrule
    \Gamma = x^2 & \beta [deg]  & 1       & 2        & 3        & 4        \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to center the cells of the first row starting from the third column? Also, is there an automatic way to write `[deg]` in text mode so that only the math expressions are written in math mode?

Comment: with use of  `X[c,si]`

Comment: @Zarko How can I make the **left** separation of the first column equal to the **right** separation of the last column equal to zero?

Comment: Add `@{}` to the beginning and the end of `colspec`.

Comment: @Diaa, adding `@{}` as mentioned in comment of L.J.R. But in this case content of the left cell will touch to the left table border. This problem you can eliminate b< omitting vertical lines or reduce by use defining first column as `>{$\relax}X[c]<{$}`.

Comment: `colspec = { @{} *{2}{>{$\relax}X[l, 0.7]<{$}} *{4}{X[1.1, c, si]} @{} }` gets this https://i.ibb.co/sChzs4p/image.png

Comment: @L.J.R. Is my last comment an issue to be resolved later?

Comment: What is the problem there?

Comment: `colspec = { @{} *{2}{>{$\relax}X[l, 0.7]<{$}} *{4}{X[1.1, c, si]} @{} }` should remove the right space between the last column and the rightmost margin, which is not what I got as shown here https://i.ibb.co/sChzs4p/image.png

Comment: No, because you are centering the cells. You may use right alignment for the last column instead.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools,siunitx}


% \usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx, array}
\sisetup{
    table-format = 2.2,
    round-precision = 2,
    round-mode = places,
    round-integer-to-decimal = true
}

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{2}{>{$\relax}c<{$}} *{4}{S}}
        \toprule
        & \delta [deg] & {{{5}}} & {{{10}}} & {{{15}}} & {{{20}}} \\
        \midrule
        \Gamma = x^2 & \beta [deg] & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...can you explain how this answers the question?