# Why is my Table Flowing Over into the Right Margin?

Tags: tables, margins, center, overflow

I have the following code which defines a table in a paper I'm writing:

```
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}} }
    \hline \hline
    Atom Pair & \ch{D0} (eV) & $\alpha$ (1/\AA) & \ch{r0} (\AA) & Cut Off (\AA) \\
    \hline
    Fe-Fe & 0.764 & 1.5995 & 2.7361 & 12 \\
    Fe-Ti & 0.8162 & 1.448 & 2.914 & 12 \\
    Fe-Nd & 0.6036 & 1.6458 & 3.188 & 12 \\
    Nd-Nd & 0.312 & 0.945 & 4.092 & 12 \\
    Nd-Ti & 0.4964 & 1.440118 & 3.4309 & 12 \\
    Ti-Ti & 0.6540 & 1.2118 & 3.3476 & 12 \\
    Sm-Sm & 0.2365 & 1.16433 & 3.8485 & 12 \\
    Sm-Ti & 0.5219 & 1.98644 & 3.3129 & 12 \\
    Sm-Fe & 0.5891 & 1.48848 & 3.1394 & 12 \\
    Sm-Co & 0.5686 & 1.47399 & 3.1725 & 12 \\
    Ti-Co & 0.7527 & 1.40291 & 2.9331 & 12 \\
    Co-Co & 0.6774 & 1.64306 & 2.7093 & 12 \\
    \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table of all the values used for the Morse potentials used for the following study.}
    \label{tab:morse_potential_values_rt12}
\end{table}
```

To avoid any ambiguity, the `\ch` command is part of the chemical formula package, the documentation for which is here: https://latex-cookbook.net/chemistry/ . It seems to me that by defining each column with `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}` I should have a table that fits the width of the text section of the page. However, when I create this table I get the following:

[image: Image of Table overflowing into margin.]

As you can see from the red lines which roughly match where the margin is, the right hand side has flowed over, although the caption below hasn't. Why is this?

Comment: You did not take into account the value of tabcolsep, the small horizontal white space that is added to the left and right of each cell's contents.

Comment: Since you don't need linebreaks inside of cells, it would be easier to use regular c type columns in combination with tabular* and \extracolsep

Comment: Okay thankyou, how can I take this into account? What is it's value, and can I set it to zero for this table only?

Comment: @leandriis If you would write an answer showing any of these methods I'd happily accept it, I'm just interested in doing the most expedient least easily broken thing!

Comment: @leandriis It seems \def is local? Is that correct? I have some def statements and they don't change anything else outside of the table environment they are in.

Comment: How or where is `\ch` defined?

Comment: @Mico \ch is from the chemical formula package defined here: https://latex-cookbook.net/chemistry/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By setting the *usable* width of each column to `0.2\textwidth`, the *total* width of each column becomes `0.2\textwidth+2\tabcolsep`, as LaTeX by default inserts `\tabcolsep` of whitespace padding on each side. Since the `tabular` environment contains 5 columns, its total width is `\textwidth+10\tabcolsep`. In many document classes, the default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`; `10\tabcolsep` thus amounts to `60pt`, i.e., roughly .83in or 2.1cm. Having the table protrude into the right-hand margin by that amount is definitely noticeable!

One *could* go about fixing this situation by reducing the width of each `m`-type column to `0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep`. However, I would like to recommend that you switch to a `tabular*` environment (with target width `\textwidth`), employ `l`, `c`, and `S`-type columns, and let LaTeX adjust the amount of intercolumn whitespace automatically so as to "fill up" the width of the text block. The `S` column type, which is provided by the `siunitx` package, is very handy for aligning numbers on their explicit or implicit decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1,group-digits=false]}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t]
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
          l T{1.4} T{1.6} T{1.4} c }
    \toprule
    Atom Pair & {$D_0$ (eV)} & {$\alpha$ (1/\AA)} & {$r_0$ (\AA)} & {Cut Off (\AA)} \\ 
    \midrule
        Fe-Fe & 0.764  & 1.5995  & 2.7361 & 12 \\
        Fe-Ti & 0.8162 & 1.448   & 2.914  & 12 \\
        Fe-Nd & 0.6036 & 1.6458  & 3.188  & 12 \\
        Nd-Nd & 0.312  & 0.945   & 4.092  & 12 \\ \addlinespace
        Nd-Ti & 0.4964 & 1.440118& 3.4309 & 12 \\
        Ti-Ti & 0.6540 & 1.2118  & 3.3476 & 12 \\
        Sm-Sm & 0.2365 & 1.16433 & 3.8485 & 12 \\
        Sm-Ti & 0.5219 & 1.98644 & 3.3129 & 12 \\ \addlinespace
        Sm-Fe & 0.5891 & 1.48848 & 3.1394 & 12 \\
        Sm-Co & 0.5686 & 1.47399 & 3.1725 & 12 \\
        Ti-Co & 0.7527 & 1.40291 & 2.9331 & 12 \\
        Co-Co & 0.6774 & 1.64306 & 2.7093 & 12 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{Table of all values used for the Morse potentials used in the following study.}
    \label{tab:morse_potential_values_rt12}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! What does \extracolsep{\fill}} mean?

Comment: @Connor - `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` is a well known LaTeX trick -- actually, well known primarily to frequent LaTeX document writers --  to get the width of the `tabular*` environment occupy the intended width (here: `\textwidth`). In words, it inserts extra whitespace in the intercolumn spaces. For for more on `tabular*` see, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56552/5001) to the query [How to force a table into page width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10535/5001) (Shameless self-citation alert.)

Comment: Awesome thankyou! How come you set `tabcolsep` to zero anyway? Why is it not a problem in the `tabular*` environment?

Comment: @Connor - The total amount of whitespace between columns is `2\tabcolsep+\fill`, where `\fill` is infinitely stretchable. Setting `\tabcolsep` to zero is just a  automatic setting of mine, an old habit if you prefer. If it's not needed, no harm done; oftentimes, though, it *is* needed, especially when one has a table with many columns. (8 or more is "many" in my view.)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two alternative versions. The first one uses fixed with `m` type columns as the original code did but instead of using `0.2\textwidth` as the width, I substracted `2\tabcolsep` from each cell's width using `\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep`. Since the contents won't spread over multiple lines, you could also use regular `c` type columns and make sure that the table is as wide as the textwidth using `tabular*` instead of `tabular`. You can then evenly distribute the extra width using `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`as in the second example table.

Both examples result in the following output: (Red lines indicate margins.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}} }
    \hline \hline
    Atom Pair & \ch{D0} (eV) & $\alpha$ (1/\AA) & \ch{r0} (\AA) & Cut Off (\AA) \\
    \hline
    Fe-Fe & 0.764 & 1.5995 & 2.7361 & 12 \\
    Fe-Ti & 0.8162 & 1.448 & 2.914 & 12 \\
    \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table of all the values used for the Morse potentials used for the following study.}
    \label{tab:morse_potential_values_rt12}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{4}{c}}
    \hline \hline
    Atom Pair & \ch{D0} (eV) & $\alpha$ (1/\AA) & \ch{r0} (\AA) & Cut Off (\AA) \\
    \hline
    Fe-Fe & 0.764 & 1.5995 & 2.7361 & 12 \\
    Fe-Ti & 0.8162 & 1.448 & 2.914 & 12 \\
    \hline \hline
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{Table of all the values used for the Morse potentials used for the following study.}
    \label{tab:morse_potential_values_rt12}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of nice (+1) @Mico answer.

- used is `tabularray` package
- columns have equal width (used are `X` column type)
- a vertical space of `1ex` is inserted after every third rows in table body

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachthree}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{3}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t]
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[l] 
                        X[c,si={table-format=1.4}]
                        X[c,si={table-format=1.6}]
                        X[c,si={table-format=1.4}]
                        X[c] @{}},
             row{2-Z}  = {rowsep=0pt},
             row{eachthree} = {abovesep=1ex},
            }
    \toprule
Atom Pair 
      & {{{$D_0$ (eV)}}} 
               & {{{$\alpha$ (1/\AA)}}} 
                          & {{{$r_0$ (\AA)}}} 
                                   & Cut Off (\AA)  \\
    \midrule
Fe-Fe & 0.764  & 1.5995   & 2.7361 & 12 \\
Fe-Ti & 0.8162 & 1.448    & 2.914  & 12 \\
Fe-Nd & 0.6036 & 1.6458   & 3.188  & 12 \\
Nd-Nd & 0.312  & 0.945    & 4.092  & 12 \\
Nd-Ti & 0.4964 & 1.440118 & 3.4309 & 12 \\
Ti-Ti & 0.6540 & 1.2118   & 3.3476 & 12 \\
Sm-Sm & 0.2365 & 1.16433  & 3.8485 & 12 \\
Sm-Ti & 0.5219 & 1.98644  & 3.3129 & 12 \\
Sm-Fe & 0.5891 & 1.48848  & 3.1394 & 12 \\
Sm-Co & 0.5686 & 1.47399  & 3.1725 & 12 \\
Ti-Co & 0.7527 & 1.40291  & 2.9331 & 12 \\
Co-Co & 0.6774 & 1.64306  & 2.7093 & 12 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Table of all values used for the Morse potentials used in the following study.}
\label{tab:morse_potential_values_rt12}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working off the helpful comment from @leandriss, I fixed the problem by adding a `\def` which changes the tabcolsep value to zero. The code is now the follwing:

```
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \def\tabcolsep{0}
    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}}}
    \hline \hline
    Atom Pair & \ch{D0} (eV) & $\alpha$ (1/\AA) & \ch{r0} (\AA) & Cut Off (\AA) \\
    \hline
    Fe-Fe & 0.764 & 1.5995 & 2.7361 & 12 \\
    Fe-Ti & 0.8162 & 1.448 & 2.914 & 12 \\
    Fe-Nd & 0.6036 & 1.6458 & 3.188 & 12 \\
    Nd-Nd & 0.312 & 0.945 & 4.092 & 12 \\
    Nd-Ti & 0.4964 & 1.440118 & 3.4309 & 12 \\
    Ti-Ti & 0.6540 & 1.2118 & 3.3476 & 12 \\
    Sm-Sm & 0.2365 & 1.16433 & 3.8485 & 12 \\
    Sm-Ti & 0.5219 & 1.98644 & 3.3129 & 12 \\
    Sm-Fe & 0.5891 & 1.48848 & 3.1394 & 12 \\
    Sm-Co & 0.5686 & 1.47399 & 3.1725 & 12 \\
    Ti-Co & 0.7527 & 1.40291 & 2.9331 & 12 \\
    Co-Co & 0.6774 & 1.64306 & 2.7093 & 12 \\
    \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table of all the values used for the Morse potentials used for the following study.}
    \label{tab:morse_potential_values_rt12}
\end{table}
```

The only addition to the code is on the 4th line, and is `\def\tabcolsep{0}` which sets the table column separation to zero within the table environment. I am not certain of this, but it seems `\def` is local to this environment, and so changes made to global variables are only effective within the table environment. This addition gives me a table of the expected width, which can be seen below:

[image: Aligned Table.]

Thankyou @Mico for the edit to the column designations.

Comment: Sorry, but setting `\tabcolsep` to zero is not a good idea here, unless you can guarantee that the contents of all cells will never exceed 0.2\textwidth.

Comment: @Mico In this instance where I have defined them all to be `0.2\textwidth` wide I guess that is a guarantee I'm bound to make either way! But regardless, I am a rookie, and I would love a better answer, if you'd be willing to write one or point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful!

Comment: You can also set `*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}`, this will keep the gap between the columns.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: This code requires the `calc` package or alternatively `\dimexpr`.

Comment: @leandriis True! Thank you for pointing this out!