# Fitting table to textwidth without packages and keeping centered text alignment

Tags: tables, width, textwidth

I am working on a machine where I currently cannot import packages. I want to fit a table into textwidth without the usual package. I managed to do this fixing the column width manually using  `p{2cm}` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-force-a-table-into-page-width). But the problem is that then the text in the columns are not centered anymore, which I would like for all except the left one.

**MWE of main document**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \input{table.tex}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

**MWE of Table**

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}}
    Hi & Hi & Hi \\
    \hline
    11 & 0 & 1111 \\
    1 & 0 & 314 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: just use \centering in the cells and end table rows with \tabularnrwline.  but you could use packages if you can write a file table.tex then you can save a copy of array.sty at the same place

Comment: I can't import files, I could retype the package code, but it's too long. Would you put \centering in each cell then?

Comment: you could use a standard `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ccc}` but why do you want to spread the columns out, it just makes the table hard to read.

Comment: Ah, tabular* is not a package? Great. The real issue is that somehow the columns stretch longer than the content of the table and thus more than textwidth. I am outputting the tex file from another software and somehow the tables are far too wide.

Comment: well `tabular*` will not help with that at all, it is for _stretching_  tables to be wider than they would be as in the example you postd. For tables where you want line wrapping in the cells you need `p` columns as you show. Bu the no package requirement honestly makes no sense here, If you have laex at all you have packages such as tabularx, it is a condition of distributing latex that they are available.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is use of the `tabularray` package:

- main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \input{table.tex}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

- table code:

```
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l,wd=2cm]Q[c,wd=2cm]Q[c,wd=2cm]}}
    Hi & Hi & Hi    \\
    \hline
    11 & 0  & 1111  \\
    1  & 0  & 314
\end{tblr}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the question considered doing this without packages.

Comment: Sorry, what you like to have, is not possible without of them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to reinvent the world, but it is possible to obtain what you want with the standard package `array` and its wc column type (I added vertical lines in the table to make obvious the table contents are centred in their columns):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \input{table.tex}
    \end{table}
    \clearpage

    \end{document} 

    \begin{tabular}{|wc{2cm}|wc{2cm}|wc{2cm}|}
        Hi & Hi & Hi \\
        \hline
        11 & 0 & 1111 \\
        1 & 0 & 314 \\
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]