# Adding graphics in-between a multicol-environment

Tags: graphics, multicol

I'm pratically using the multicol-environment with 2 columns and trying to insert a table in-between in a one-page layout (meaning using up the full-page width) and then after start using the multicol-environment again without any page breaks. Is that possible? Would be nice if someone could create a code example :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide `MWE` of your code

Comment: it is very possible, but you cannot guarantee no page breaks.  You could test if there is enough room left on the page, although multicol is tricky about `\pagetotal` and `\pagegoal`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your question has anything to do with the `multicol` environment. Are you really asking "How do I make a table stretch the full width of the page?" If that is the case, one potential solution is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56552/245702)

This worked for me. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[letter]{report}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[5]
\end{multicols}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular*}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[5]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[full width table between two multicol environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbCjB.png)

You did not state which document class you are using, so your results may vary depending on that and other packages you have loaded. I also tried this with the `article` class and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[letter]{report}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{multicols}

    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}\\
        Caption figure with long text and more text for description
    \end{center}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1-3]
        You can have also a small figure in one column, whith a short caption.
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}\\
            Short caption
        \end{center}
        \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \end{multicols}
    \lipsum[5]
    
\end{document}
```