3rd column of a table is out of page
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Feature} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Q-Learning}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{DDQN}} \\ \hline
Function Approximation & No, uses a Q-table for state-action values. & Yes, uses deep neural networks to approximate Q-values. \\ \hline
Scalability & Limited to small state and action spaces. & Scales well to large and continuous state spaces. \\ \hline
Overestimation Bias & Prone to overestimation of Q-values. & Reduces overestimation bias by decoupling action selection and evaluation. \\ \hline
Learning Stability & Can be unstable and diverge in complex environments. & More stable learning process due to target network. \\ \hline
Exploration Efficiency & Simple exploration mechanisms like $\epsilon$-greedy. & Efficient exploration with experience replay and target network updates.\\ \hline
Sample Efficiency & Low, requires a large number of interactions with the environment. & Higher, reuses past experiences for learning.\\ \hline
Convergence Speed & Slower, especially in large or complex environments. & Faster convergence due to stable training and reduced bias.\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Difference between Q-Learning and DDQN}
\label{tab:Ql_vs_SRS}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}

The result I get is this 
I cannot see DDQN column at all and it is outside of range of page. How can I solve this problem?

You need to use p{<width>} columns or tabularx with X columns at least for the second and third column. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2441/277964 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10535/277964.

You need to allow automatic line-breaking in at least columns 2 and 3, and ideally in all three columns. Unfortunately, the c and l column types do not allow automatic line-breaking.
I suggest you switch from a tabular to a tabularx environment and set its target width to \textwidth. In the code below, I use the L column type for all three columns; the L column type is just like the basic X column type of the tabularx environment, except that it doesn't impose full justification (while still allowing hyphenation).
Separately, I'd also give the table a much more open and inviting "look" by getting rid of all vertical rules and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules. And, do consider not using bold-facing for the material in the header row.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{array} % 'array' is loaded automatically by 'tabularx'
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\nobreakdash' macro
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}LLL@{}}
\toprule
Feature & Q-Learning & DDQN \\ 
\midrule
Function Approximation & No, uses a Q-table for state-action values. 
                       & Yes, uses deep neural networks to approximate Q\nobreakdash-values. \\ 
                       \addlinespace
Scalability            & Limited to small state and action spaces. 
                       & Scales well to large and continuous state spaces. \\ 
                       \addlinespace
Overestimation Bias    & Prone to overestimation of Q\nobreakdash-values. 
                       & Reduces overestimation bias by decoupling action selection and evaluation. \\ 
                       \addlinespace
Learning Stability     & Can be unstable and diverge in complex environments. 
                       & More stable learning process due to target network. \\ 
                       \addlinespace
Exploration Efficiency & Simple exploration mechanisms like $\epsilon$\nobreakdash-greedy. 
                       & Efficient exploration with experience replay and target network updates. \\ 
                       \addlinespace
Sample Efficiency      & Low, requires a large number of interactions with the environment. 
                       & Higher, reuses past experiences for learning. \\ 
                       \addlinespace
Convergence Speed      & Slower, especially in large or complex environments. 
                       & Faster convergence due to stable training and reduced bias. \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Differences between Q-Learning and DDQN}
\label{tab:Ql_vs_SRS}

\end{table}

\end{document}


Thanks @Mico How can I put it in a horizontal line for each row?

@MacTavish - You could replace the \addlinespace instructions with \midrule. Speaking for myself (who else?), though, I'd go with the more open look provided by the \addlinespace approach to row separation.

Got it @Mico Thanks
